# Where do I get info to create metadata for OpenStreetMap layers?

Tags: metadata, openstreetmap

I was asked to create metadata (INSPIRE) for one gdataset extracted from Open Street Map. I downloaded the polygon layer and added basic information but I don't know where to find more information than this : http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/land-polygons 
I have been looking for 2 hours now and I think I will go crazy soon.
So if anyone knows, thank you a lot.

Cheers,

I am especially looking about data quality !

Answer (score 1):

You will not find complete metadata information about the polygon file you downloaded. 
The source where you downloaded the OSM data unfortunately does not have any id associated with the polygons. If you download the data for example from [Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/) the data will have an id associated. This way you can look up the individual lines and might get further information about the way they were created or the author.

Inspire Metadata are in XML format. You probably have to create that from scratch. There are no OSM XML metadata available as far as I know.

Comment: Also you might want to check this out: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19532/ways-to-access-and-download-the-metadata-of-openstreetmaps